# How to perform cython files compilation in parallel?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython, cythonize

I would like to perform `cython` files compilation in parallel.

So, I take a look at `Cython.Build` source file, and find the following signature for `cythonize` function:

```
def cythonize(module_list, exclude=None, nthreads=0, aliases=None,
              quiet=False, force=False, language=None,
              exclude_failures=False, **options):
```

And the following comment about cythonize `nthreads` option:

```
"For parallel compilation, set the 'nthreads' option to the number of
concurrent builds."
```

So I tried to use this option in my `setup.py` file, like that:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils.extension import Extension

EXTENSIONS = [Extension(...)
              ...
              Extension(...)]

setup(name='...',
      ...
      ext_modules=cythonize(EXTENSIONS, nthreads=8),
      ...)
```

But my `.pyx` files are still compiled sequentially using 1 thread.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong here and how to use `nthreads` option to perform `cythonize` compilation in parallel ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found a solution to compile my cython file in parallel:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils.extension import Extension

NB_COMPILE_JOBS = 8

EXTENSIONS = [Extension(...)
              ...
              Extension(...)]

def setup_given_extensions(extensions):
    setup(name='...',
          ...
          ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
          ...)

def setup_extensions_in_sequential():
    setup_given_extensions(EXTENSIONS)

def setup_extensions_in_parallel():
    cythonize(EXTENSIONS, nthreads=NB_COMPILE_JOBS)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=NB_COMPILE_JOBS)
    pool.map(setup_given_extensions, EXTENSIONS)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if "build_ext" in sys.argv:
    setup_extensions_in_parallel()
else:
    setup_extensions_in_sequential()
```

Comment: Running `setup(..)` in several parallel processes, couldn't it have some unexpected side effects?

Answer (score 14):

Cython builds are a two step process:

1. source.py to source.c
2. source.c to source.o

The `nthreads` argument to `cythonize()` controls the concurrency of the first process, but not the second.

For the second process `build_ext` takes a `-j` argument to control the concurrency of builds, so you can speed up your builds like this:

**`python setup.py build_ext -j 4`**

Or if you are building a wheel, you can use:

**`python setup.py build_ext -j 4 bdist_wheel`**

Comment: Can you link documentation to this answer? What are all the args to `build_ext`?